# How to use Vaadin SQLContainer when I already have a JDBC connection pool

Tags: java, database-connection, vaadin, connection-pooling, vaadin7

Vaadin 7 offers the [SQLContainer](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/util/sqlcontainer/SQLContainer.html) implementation. The [Book of Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/sqlcontainer.html) says to use either of its implementations of a JDBC connection pool. But I already am using the [Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html) implementation. Having one pool that draws from another pool seems like a bad thing.

To continue using the Tomcat pool, I implemented the [com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.connection.JDBCConnectionPool](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/util/sqlcontainer/connection/JDBCConnectionPool.html) interface. That interface requires three methods:

- `reserveConnection`
  I return a connection drawn from the Tomcat pool.
- `releaseConnection`
  I do nothing. I tried calling `close` on the connection, but that actually closed the connection rather than returning it to the Tomcat pool. Apparently the SQLContainer already called `close` once and my second call to `close` actually closes down the connection. I was getting runtime errors saying the connection was not open.
- `destroy`
  I do nothing. Supposedly this method is just some workaround for some issue with Postgres (which I'm using), but seems irrelevant given that I am actually using the Tomcat pool.

➜ Is implementing that interface the correct approach?

➜ If implementing that interface is the way to go, did I do so properly? Any other issues I should address?

My Tomcat pool is available via JNDI, so I'm not sure if I should be using the Vaadin class [J2EEConnectionPool](https://vaadin.com/api/7.3.1/com/vaadin/data/util/sqlcontainer/connection/J2EEConnectionPool.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should in fact be able to use J2EEConnectionPool, exactly as you described in your own answer above. I have used successfully used J2EEConnectionPool with FreeformQuery so I know this works. Unfortunately there is apparently a bug in Vaadin's TableQuery implementation which caused the "connection has been closed" error you saw. See: http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/12370

The ticket proposes a code change, but in my case I simply replaced the offending TableQuery with a FreeformQuery.

Answer (score 1):

## `J2EEConnectionPool` Is Not A Pool (a misnomer)

Having looked at [the source code](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin/blob/master/server/src/com/vaadin/data/util/sqlcontainer/connection/J2EEConnectionPool.java), it appears the [J2EEConnectionPool](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/util/sqlcontainer/connection/J2EEConnectionPool.html) class is misnamed. It is *not* an implementation of a pool. It merely draws on a javax.sql.DataSource object (obtained via JNDI if not provided to constructor) to get a java.sql.Connection object.

The "Pool" part of the name must come from an *assumption* that the DataSource is backed by a connection pool.

## Yes, Use `J2EEConnectionPool`

So, if a real connection pool is in use such as the Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool available via DataSource or JNDI, pass that DataSource or JNDI info to an instance of `J2EEConnectionPool` for use with the Vaadin SQLContainer.

## Forum Thread

See [this discussion](https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/9611575), “Any chance of bug fix for TableQuery+SQLContainer and Connection pools?”, on the Vaadin Forums.

## Bug Ticket

See [Ticket # 12370](https://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/12370), “SQLContainer does not work with tomcat/BoneCP connection pool”, in the Vaadin issue tracker.

Comment: Nope, using J2EEConnectionPool fails. I get this error: `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed.`

Comment: **IMPORTANT** See this [sibling answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27116735/642706) for a link to a Vaadin Dev Ticket explaining my above comment reporting an error. That error may be caused by a bug in the Vaadin `J2EEConnectionPool` not playing nice with the Tomcat connection pool.

Comment: Unofficial fix for above issue. Crazy that Vaadin haven't fixed already https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/9611575